# How to unprotect music files in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, finder

I had some songs from what turned out to be a bootleg (and badly done) CD.  I found the songs in the Store and bought them.  But I can't delete the bad ones.

I selected them and pressed Delete.  Nothing happened.  I selected "Delete from Library" on the menu and nothing happened.  This has worked in the past.

So I used Finder to delete the files, then tried to open the info window on them.  In the past, this would offer me the chance to locate them or delete them.  Now it's only locate.  Same for trying to play them.

I copied other files into the filenames that iTunes knows them by, and tried to delete again.  Still nothing happens.

Not long ago, I deleted other songs from the same CD import without problem.

What could be preventing deletion and how do I get rid of it?  I don't recall changing any preferences.

Comment: The versions of macOS and iTunes would be useful.

Comment: Latest versions.

Comment: Could you try to use the "locate" button and point the old song names to the files of the new songs that you bought?

Comment: No, because then I'd have two of each and still want to delete one.  Something is clearly wrong when a "delete"menu option doesn't do anything.  I want to fix the problem, not hide it.